# One task per node only in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I'm relatively new to Apache Ignite. I'm using Ignite compute to distribute tasks to nodes. My goal is a task dispatcher that produces tasks and submits these only to nodes that are "free". One node can only do one task at a time. If all nodes have a task running, the dispatcher shall wait for the next node to become available and then submit the next task.

I can implement this with a queue and async Callables, however I wonder if there is an Ignite onboard class that does something like this? Not sure the class ComputeTaskSplitAdapter is what I need to look at, I'm not fully understanding its purpose.

Any help appreciated.

Server nodes can join and leave the cluster while tasks are distributed.
Tasks can take different amount of time on the nodes and as soon as a server finishes a task it shall get the next task.

Here's my node code:

```
    JobStealingCollisionSpi spi = new JobStealingCollisionSpi();
    spi.setActiveJobsThreshold(1);

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setCollisionSpi(spi);

    Ignition.start(cfg);
```

And this is my job distribution code (for testing):

```
    JobStealingCollisionSpi spi = new JobStealingCollisionSpi();
    spi.setActiveJobsThreshold(1);

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setCollisionSpi(spi);

    Ignition.setClientMode(true);
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ignite.compute().runAsync(new IgniteRunnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.print("Sleeping...");
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Done.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org) has direct support for it. Please take a look at the [One-at-a-Time](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/job-scheduling#section-one-at-a-time) section in the Job Scheduling documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/job-scheduling#section-one-at-a-time

Note that every server has its own waiting queue and servers will move to the next job in their queue immediately after they are done with a previous job.

If you would like even more aggressive scheduling, then you can take a look at [Job-Stealing](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/collision/jobstealing/JobStealingCollisionSpi.html) scheduling here: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/collision/jobstealing/JobStealingCollisionSpi.html

With Job Stealing enabled, servers will still jobs from the job-queues on other servers once their own queue becomes empty. Most of the parameters are configurable.

Comment: Not sure this solves my particular issue as tasks can take different amount of time and also server nodes and join and stop during runtime. I want servers become available for new tasks as soon as they are done with their current task and not wait for in FIFO ordering. I don't think either FifoQueueCollisionSpi nor PriorityQueueCollisionSpi can solve this, right?

Comment: I have updated the response. I think job-stealing is something you might be looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand how using job stealing SPI can solve my issue. Note that the number of available servers is not known when the SPI is configured, servers can join/leave at runtime. So me it looks like the number of parallel jobs must be configured at startup which I think needs to be equal to the number of servers. Or am I misunderstanding? Are there examples for this SPI use case?

Comment: Parallel jobs are per node, not per cluster. You would set the number of parallel jobs to 1 on each server, this ways jobs will be executed one-at-a-time on each server. Other jobs will be accumulated and other servers, that freed up, may steal these jobs. I think that this is exactly the behavior you want, no?

Comment: I added my code into the question above. I expected the IgniteRunnable to execute on each node only one per node. But the nodes actually fail with java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted which tells me that they are executed in parallel. Is my assumption wrong? Maybe something I'm completely misunderstanding?

Comment: Interrupted exception only means that the thread running the job was interrupted. Usually this is caused by node stoppage, please check.